# TypeError: bufsize must be an integer, Python

Tags: python

```
interface= input('interface>')
mac_changer= input('new MAC> ')
print('[+] Changing MAC address for', interface, 'to', mac_changer)

subprocess.call('ifconfig', interface, 'down', shell=True)
subprocess.call('ifconfig', interface, 'hw ether', mac_changer, shell=True)
subprocess.call('ifconfig', interface, 'up', shell=True)
```

and it gives me TypeError: bufsize must be an integer!
please HELPPP

Comment: Please post the entire traceback.

Comment: If you're going to use `shell=True`, the command and its parameters should be a single string.  If you're going to use `shell=False`, the command and parameters should be elements in a list.  Either way, it all gets passed to `subprocess` as a single parameter.

Comment: what do u mean, can u post a code @jasonharper